# Arrange all images within a workspace as "cascade"

Tags: dm-script

Is there a script command to arrange all images within a workspace (GMS 3.x) as "cascade" that is equivalent using the keyboard shortcut CTL-Shift-L? WorkspaceArrange() doesn't seem to do the job, even the default auto-arrange method is changed:

[image: Quick Arrange]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `ADLMAllImageDocumentsCascade()`, but it is not an officially supported command, so it might not be available or behaving the same in all GMS versions.

You may also take a look at the help on the layout manager for some alternative image arrangement options:

[image]